# PHP Google GSuite API - setChangePasswordAtNextLogin

Tags: php, api, google-workspace

I'm trying to bulk change users "setChangePasswordAtNextLogin" value in GSuite using the PHP API.

I've no issues with changing passwords or other values, but when using "setChangePasswordAtNextLogin" it will not accept false only true.

I've tried:
false
"false"
(bool)false
0

It wont take it and save it, however if I put true it applies this value.

I'm trying to change this value for 60+ users so would like to be able to implement it in my code ideally.

Accounts may be new so I also tried using setAgreedToTerms and setIsMailboxSetup.

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Please share the full code you already tried so we can have a look.

Comment: `try {
 $findAccount = $service->users->get($userName."@----");
 $findAccount->setHashFunction("SHA-1");
 $findAccount->setPassword(hash('sha1',$pwdToUse));
 $findAccount->setChangePasswordAtNextLogin(false);
 $googleResult = $service->users->update($userName."@----",$findAccount);
 echo "<div class=\"no-print\"><h5><font color=\"green\">Google Directory password successfully changed to <b>".$pwdToUse."</b></font></h5></div>";
} catch (Google_Service_Exception $e){
 echo "<div class=\"no-print\"><h5><font color=\"red\">Google Error: <b>".$e->getMessage()."</b></font></h5></div>";
}`

Comment: This works and changes passwords perfectly fine, it's just not applying the setchangepasswordatnextlogin. The accounts are new so I'm not sure if this is just a G Suite restriction.